# Problem setting up Keil for first time for Tiva Launchpad TI TM4C1294XL MCU

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, keil, texas-instruments

I'm fairly new to embedded systems and I'm trying to set up `Keil` for a `EK-TM4C129XL Tiva Launchpad MCU` (https://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C1294XL). I downloaded the drivers from TI website, installed them. Then installed `Keilv5`, create a project, select my mcu, but when I add my `led.c` file to Source Group 1, the Runtime Environment appears empty, like this:

[image]

And it doesn't add a startup file.

I tried the `Keilv4` version, and everything works fine, adds the start file (.s), when I translate it works fine, but when I hit build target, says:

> ".axf file not found".

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the Board Support Package for your micrcontroller on Keil's website?